# How to update table with join on itself

Tags: sql, vertica

I'm trying to update a column in a table that makes a join on itself to filter out data.

Initially, the piece of code was for SQL Server and I tried to change it so it run in Vertica. I'm getting this error:
`ERROR: Syntax error at or near "inner"`

```
update REPORT.sub_2018_ALL a 
    inner join REPORT.sub_2018_ALL p 
    on a.MBR_ID= p.MBR_ID and a.NAME = p.NAME
set RESULT = 'F'
where p.STATUS_REASON = 'Submitted' and a.REVIEW_RESULT is null
```

I'm not sure if it's because of the alias or if it's not possible to update when a table joins on itself. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
update REPORT.sub_2018_ALL a 
    set RESULT = 'F'
where a.REVIEW_RESULT is null and
      exists (select 1
              from REPORT.sub_2018_ALL p 
              where a.MBR_ID = p.MBR_ID and
                    a.NAME = p.NAME and
                    p.STATUS_REASON = 'Submitted'
             );
```

For the record, your original syntax would not work on SQL Server, although it might work on MySQL.

Comment: The code I had up there is my try after converting the SQL server code to Vertica. Looks like it's working now